# How can I display a description based on errorlevel value?

Tags: batch-file, error-code, errorlevel

I'm writing a batch script to install an exe and a successful installation returns 0 and other codes mean different reasons.

I know I can print those error code(s) by `echo %errorlevel%`

Can I print the description related to the code instead? If so, how?

i.e. print 'successful' for code 0, etc.

Comment: Lots and lots of `if` statements. The actual description will vary based on what the program is, but you will have to provide the text that you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to print a message using error codes

`if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo Successful`

`if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 echo Not Successful`

Because errorlevel 0 indicates that return values of last executed command is successful,other return values have their own meaning

Answer (score 0):

You can use || to act on failure, for simplicities sake this should do fine.

```
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo Installed! || echo Install failed...
```

And && to activate on success.

```
del file.ext && echo File deleted.
```

The reason I don't provide a per errorlevel basis is that there can be up to 255 of them, something that would take an exceedingly high amount of time, and is further hindered by the tendency of programs not publically showing or ever documenting what each and every errorlevel means.

Something good to keep in mind is the difference between %errorlevel% and errorlevel. [here](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx?Redirected=true)